# Get all posts with sum of votes and if current user voted each post

Tags: sql, postgresql

If have the following two PostgreSQL tables:

**Post table:**

`postid | title | author | created`

**Vote table:**

`postid | username | vote`

where vote is equal to 1 if the user voted the post up, 0 if the user did not vote and -1 if the user voted the post down.

I want to receive now for every post its title, author, created date, sum of all votes and
the vote of the current logged in user.
I wrote a query to receive everything except the vote of the current user like this:

```sql
SELECT post.postID as postID, post.title as title, post.author as author,
       COALESCE(sum(votes.vote), 0) as voteCount, post.created as created
       FROM post LEFT JOIN votes ON post.postID = votes.postID 
       GROUP BY post.postID ORDER BY voteCount DESC
```

I tried to fetch the current userVote by running a subquery like

```sql
(SELECT vote FROM votes WHERE postID = post.postID AND username = :username) as userVote
```

However it does not seem to work and I am unable to figure out why and how to fix it.
Any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with your query. Just use `filter` clause to get current user's vote count

```sql
SELECT 
    post.postID as postID, 
    post.title as title, 
    post.author as author,
    post.created as created,
    COALESCE(sum(votes.vote), 0) as voteCount, 
    COALESCE(sum(votes.vote) filter (where votes.username= 'username'), 0) as userVote  -- in '' just provide username for current login user
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN votes ON post.postID = votes.postID 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

Another way is by using one more left join like below:

```
SELECT 
    p.postID as postID, 
    p.title as title, 
    p.author as author,
    p.created as created,
    COALESCE(sum(v1.vote), 0) as voteCount, 
    COALESCE(v2.vote , 0) as userVote  -- in '' just provide username for current login user
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN votes v1 ON p.postID = v1.postID 
LEFT JOIN votes v2 on p.postID = v2.postID and v2.username='username'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,v2.vote
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=be717c7c070e6c95337c616052173e41)

Comment: Could you explain why the second sum is necessary since the user only has one vote per post. And I suppose that the first query is more efficient since it only has one left join? But thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Because `filter` clause works with any aggregation function only. So its a hack to use it in such scenario. If it contains single value then you can use any aggregation function i.e. `max`, `min` etc.