# Problems with multiple joins and a sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, inner-join, sql-null

If have the following three PostgreSQL tables:

**Post table:**

`postid | title | author | created`

**Vote table:**

`postid | username | vote`

where vote is equal to 1 if the user voted the post up, 0 if the user did not vote and -1 if the user voted the post down.

**Comment table:**

`commentID | parentID | postID | content | author | created`

where the parentID is null if the comment is not a reply.

I want to receive now for every post its title, author, created date, sum of all votes and
the vote of the current logged in user and the number of comments.
I already had problems with the vote of the user and asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64368927/get-all-posts-with-sum-of-votes-and-if-current-user-voted-each-post) and someone helped me to get the following query:

```sql
SELECT post.postID as postID, post.title as title, post.author as author,
       post.created as created,
       COALESCE(sum(votes.vote), 0) as voteCount,
       COALESCE(sum(votes.vote) FILTER (WHERE votes.username = :username), 0) as userVote
       FROM post 
       LEFT JOIN votes ON post.postID = votes.postID 
       GROUP BY post.postID 
       ORDER BY voteCount DESC
```

Now I tried another `LEFT JOIN` to fetch the number of comments like this:

```sql
COUNT(DISTINCT comments) FILTER (WHERE comments.parentID IS NULL) as numComments
LEFT JOIN comments on post.postID = comments.postID
```

However, while the number of comments work, the number of votes on each post is wrong since
due to the other join the rows seem to appear multiple times yielding a wrong sum and I have some trouble figuring out a way to solve this.

I already tried to fetch the number of comments as a subquery so that it is independent from the
number of votes without success.
Any further help would be very appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically pre-aggregate in subqueries before joining, like so:

```
SELECT p.*
    COALESCE(v.voteCount, 0) as voteCount,
    COALESCE(v.userVote, 0) as userVote,
    COALESCE(c.numComments, 0) as numComments
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT postID, 
        SUM(vote) as voteCount, 
        SUM(vote) FILTER (WHERE username = :username) userVote
    FROM votes 
    GROUP BY postID
) v ON v.postID = p.postID 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT postID, count(*) numComments
    FROM comments
    WHERE parentID IS NULL
    GROUP BY postID
) c ON c.postID = p.postID
ORDER BY voteCount DESC
```

Comment: This will not work if the database requires full groups. You would need to join by postID, vote, username.

Answer (score 0):

Count the values separately.  The `join`s are causing a Cartesian product.  This is a place where correlated subqueries or lateral joins help:

```
SELECT p.*, v.*, c.*
FROM post p CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT SUM(v.vote) as voteCount,
             SUM(v.vote) FILTER (WHERE v.username = :username), 0) as userVote
      FROM votes v
      WHERE p.postID = v.postID 
     ) v CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT SUM(c.vote) as commentCount,
             SUM(c.vote) FILTER (WHERE c.username = :username), 0) as userVote
      FROM comments c
      WHERE p.postID = c.postID 
     ) c
ORDER BY voteCount DESC;
```